# Can't use attribute with percent sign and curly braces

Tags: pug

Trying to compile twig files from pug, it seems impossible to use twig's {%...%} in tags for adding conditional attributes like so:

```
input( {% if required %}required{% endif %} )
```

expected output:

```
<input {% if required %}required{% endif %} />
```

Tried many workarounds without success so far, any idea?

Comment: Maybe `input({%='', if='', required='', %}required{%='', endif='', %}='')` will work?

Comment: Nope it does not, it compiles in `<input {%="" if="" required="" %}required{%="" endif="" %}="">`